# Exclude an item and its content elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

There are tons of elements in my page and I'm trying to make only a `div` including all its content printable.

I have this css:

```
@media print
{    
    .no-print, .no-print *
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Now before `</body>` I want to run a jQuery code so that adds `.no-print` class to every `div` but `.content` and its containing elements.

to exclude `.content` I know what I have to do:

```
$('div:not(.content)').addClass('no-print');
```

But to also exclude its content I tried:

```
$('div:not(.content,.content *)').addClass('no-print');
```

and

```
$('div:not(.content),div:not(.content *)').addClass('no-print');
```

but none of them have the desired result. The code adds `.no-print` to all of the divs. and printing shows an empty page.

**Update:**
I don't think html would be required in here. but as comments ask for it, I add an example:

```
<div>
   <div class="header">...</div>
   <div class="nav">...</div>
   <div class="menu>
       <ul>
          <li>menu item 1</li>
          <li>menu item 2</li>
          <li>menu item 3</li>
          <li>menu item 4</li>
          <li>menu item 5</li>
      </ul>       
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">...</div>
   <div class="content">
       <div><table>....</table></div>
       <div><table>....</table></div>
       <div><table>....</table></div>
  </div>
   <div class="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do share complete code... Including `HTML`

Comment: You probably have some other div containing the div.content that's being affected by your print styles.

Comment: @BoltClock well there are lots of `div`s inside `.content` thats why i'm trying to also exclude its content elements

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani: Doesn't matter. You have one div that's containing div.content (and the HTML you've now edited in shows this). Since that other div is :not(.content) it's going to receive the display: none style and your content div will be hidden. You need to add a class to that div as well so it won't be affected.

Comment: oh I got you wrong. now I got what you mean. how to exclde its parents too?

Comment: Or you could use div:not(:has(.content), .content, .content *) and save having to add an extra class.

Comment: I changed my css to: ` @media print
{    
    div:not(:has(.admin-content), .admin-content, .admin-content *)
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
}` and its printing everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use filter:

```
var elements = $('div:not(.content) *').filter(function(index, element) {
      return $(this).closest('div.content').length == 0;
});
```

```js
$(function () {
  var elements = $('div:not(.content) *').filter(function(index, element) {
    return $(this).closest('div.content').length == 0;
  });
  
  elements.each(function(index, element) {
       console.log(index + ' --->  ' + element.outerHTML.substring(0, 30) + '....');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div class="header">YES...</div>
    <div class="nav">YES...</div>
    <div class="menu">
        YES
       <ul>
           YES
          <li>menu item 1</li>
          <li>menu item 2</li>
          <li>menu item 3</li>
          <li>menu item 4</li>
          <li>menu item 5</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">YES...</div>
<div class="content">
    NO
    <div>NO<table>....</table></div>
    <div>NO<table>....</table></div>
    <div>NO<table>....</table></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">YES...</div>
</div>
```